# Radio Button inside radion group doesn't remains selected in Android

Tags: android, radio-button, status, radio-group

I have three radio buttons inside one radio group. I had basically made all radio buttons unselected by removing set selected line from xml file. Now when user selects any button it only works for one time, when again it goes to radio button selection window it had lost all before selection state. I had tried so many statements but hadn't got succeed. Means I want when user checks any button it will be always remain selected until user doesn't check any other button. Please help me. Below is my code.

SelectedLanguage.java:

```
public class SelectLanguage extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static String lang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_language);

        RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        RadioButton gujarati = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RadioButton hindi = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        RadioButton english = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        //int radio_selected = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("my_selected_radio",0);
        //int radio_selected = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("my_selected_radio",selectedValue).commit();

        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(checkedId == R.id.radio0) {
                    lang = "Gujarati";

                } else if(checkedId == R.id.radio1) {
                    lang = "Hindi";

                } else {
                    lang = "English";

                }

            }

        });

    }
```

select_language.xml:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: When another activity(screen) is started, the previous activity goes in pause state else if you finish(); it, it is destroyed, so the simple solution is to save your checked item index or the string locally in a SharedPreference and retrieve them in OnCreate() and set Checkbox selection based on previous user selection, this is the easiest way you can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complete answer for your need, I had tried this and this is working perfect. This code stores the value of selected checkbox in sharedpreferances and when required it returns the stored value.

```
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        Editor editor1 = pref.edit();
        editor1.remove("key_name");
        if (checkedId == R.id.radio0) {
            lang = "Gujarati";
            pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
            Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("key_name", lang);
            editor.commit();
            // chk = pref.getString("key_name", null);
            txtV.setText(lang);

        } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio1) {
            lang = "Hindi";
            pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
            Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("key_name", lang);
            editor.commit();
            // chk = pref.getString("key_name", null);
            txtV.setText(lang);
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio2) {
            lang = "English";
            pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
            Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("key_name", lang);
            editor.commit();
            // chk = pref.getString("key_name", null);
            txtV.setText(lang);

        }
    }

});

pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
chk = pref.getString("key_name", null);
System.err.println("Get value is=====" + chk);
if (chk != null) {
    if (chk.equals("Gujarati")) {
        gujarati.setChecked(true);
    }
    if (chk.equals("Hindi")) {
        hindi.setChecked(true);
    }
    if (chk.equals("English")) {
        english.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please describe the actual flow? Does it involve the user selecting the radio button, the screen is closed, and then the user goes back to the same screen and you want to display the previsouly-selected radio button as selected?

If that's the case, I believe you need to specifically set the checked/selected radio button with something like:
    ((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(INDEX)).setChecked(true);

Comment: user goes to selection window by clicking button and then user checks any checkbox, but when user goes to that selection screen again, there is all checkbox gone to unchecked state, also if user starts the application again by closing it then it also forgets everything about checked status.

Comment: do you please provide me any link which have guideline about SharedPreference.

Comment: Okay, so as I mentioned, the framework doesn't re-check the button that the user selected in a previous selection or session.

What you need to do is save the value selected in the application's Preferences or SQLite DB (depending on the nature of the value) - and when the screen is opened - check if a value was previously stored - and let your code select that radio button with something like the snippet I posted above.

If you need more info about saving data in Android, you might want to start here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Comment: And more specifically - SharedPreferences: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: is there any reliable way than storing values to db?

Comment: Finally I had made complete code using SharedPreferances. Thanks.